# Process UTF-16LE encoded file in hadoop/cascading

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cascading, utf-16le

I need to process a UTF-16LE encoded file in cascading on top of hadoop. I've tried following approaches but none of these are working.

- While assigning value `-Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-16LE` to
  property `mapreduce.map.java.opts` in **mapred-site.xml** 
  failed due to NullPointerException at:  `com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:187)` But this method works for UTF-8. Is hadoop unable to process UTF-16 data?
- Doing `System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-16LE");` in code is also
  unable to parse the data
- Overriding charset of TextDelimited class of    Cascading is also
  unable to process data

However using BufferedReader to read it in UTF-16LE parses the data correctly.

Please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Found out somewhere: Hadoop doesn't support UTF-16 files